# Guitar pickup and headphones common ground

Tags: ground, ground-loop, headphones, guitar-pedal

Trying to get rid of cables on stage.
Is it possible to have a shared common ground for my guitar pickup and monitoring headphones (with a clip on headphone amp) without getting a signal loop?

Something like this will give me a signal feedback loop when I stop playing:

[image]

Comment: Can you improve the sketch some more? "Pedal" suggests a stomp box on the floor but your text mentions clip-on amp. Draw dotted boxes to signify what's in the guitar, what's in the amplifier and where the connectors are.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I updated the diagram now. The clip on amp is the amp close to the headphone.

Comment: If you just want to reduce cables, why not use a cable with more cores, like a cat5e cable? That would give you 4 pairs to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @user1937198's suggestion to use a cable with more cores/conductors. I'm not sure if cat5-type cable would "survive" working in performance venues, but there are cables that might meet the need. For example, here's one (just picked quickly from web search): https://www.markertek.com/product/mr202-2at/canare-mr202-2at-2-pair-twisted-pair-multi-channel-mic-cable-by-the-ft
(BTW, no endorsement of cable or seller.)

It's usually not a good idea to combine ground returns due to possible "common impedance coupling," where currents from different sources flow through the same common impedance (ground wire, in this case).

Also, as has been mentioned, you could have a crosstalk problem where different signals travel a significant distance on wires close to one another and the signal from one appears on the other.

The cable suggested (and others like it) addresses both issues by having individual twisted pairs inside a shield.

Comment: cat5e cable is getting pretty common in performance venues these days, and survives well enough. (Things like digital audio networks, artnet, DMX multicores among other things), But any 4+ core cable would do.

Comment: Thanks, I believe the this is the way to go. I just hoped to be able to use my current cable before going back to the workbench.

Comment: Going through a lot of CAT 5e-cables, most of them aren't actually shielded. Also the shielded ones have foil shielding, which is not very durable. I found a different type of cable with braided shielding and 4 cores which was suitable instead..

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems that you are probably confusing:

- Ground loop: this can pick up hum.
- Cross-talk: your stomp box output signal level may be much higher than the guitar signal and may cross-talk into the pickup signal and give some feedback.

It's hard to say how much of a problem this would be so you could experiment to find out.

[image]

You can eliminate the first problem by removing the ground wire marked with 'X's. The headphone audio out will be referenced to the audio in ground.

Comment: Thank you the idea. Unfortunately it didn't work to cut the headphone ground by the tele plug. Still got a signal loop. I guess cat5e cable is the way to go.

Comment: "*Still got a signal loop.*" What does that mean?